# Cannot use AccountUsers property in Account SOAP object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I would like to retrieve all AccountUsers associated with an account. I'm using the following SOAP request (using a Retrieve SOAPAction):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Account</ObjectType>
            <Properties>AccountUsers</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:84c37169-ad53-4506-8c2b-927575e2a5f3</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9f579d5d-77a1-4f26-bc37-7c24452405c2</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-300e5c3e-72b5-4678-bd73-38962f00ccb9">
                <wsu:Created>2014-02-03T09:16:26Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2014-02-03T09:21:26Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) AccountUsers do not match with the fields of Account retrieve</OverallStatus><RequestID>bf29e1da-ac3e-4952-b649-14b3a3613d77</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The property AccountUsers is documented in the [Account object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/account/) so this should work. I can use the same request to retrieve other properties like City, AccountType, etc.

Please can someone confirm if this is a bug or if there is a workaround to retrieve all AccountUsers in an Account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AccountUser property in the Account Object is more of a setter. If you'd like to retrieve all the users in an account then you will need to do a Retrieve on the AccountUser object itself.

Here's some working XML

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </s:Body>
```