# API for User Creation in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Does there exist an API method to create users in Marketing Cloud? I checked the documentation and couldn't find one. Want to be double sure that I didn't overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm) object.

There are several examples here on SFSE and in the official documentation:

**SFMC Help**

- [Adding a New User to an Existing Account](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_a_new_user_to_an_existing_account/)

**SFSE**

- [Cannot use AccountUsers property in Account SOAP object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/cannot-use-accountusers-property-in-account-soap-object)
- [ExactTarget/Marketing Cloud SOAP account creation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84263/exacttarget-marketing-cloud-soap-account-creation)

Comment: Yea Adam.. I found it out just few mins back. Thanks !